# How to fix timeout exception while running headless browser on selenium?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, jenkins-pipeline

I'm encountering an issue with my TestNG framework when running test cases on Chrome with headless mode enabled. All the tests pass without headless mode, but with headless mode, I'm getting the following error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: Proxy element for: DefaultElementLocator 'By.xpath: //div[text()='Login']' (tried for 30 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)
```

--- Information about

- Selenium version: selenium-java 4.12.0
- Chrome driver version: 120.0.6099.109
- Chrome browser version: 121.0.6167.185
- Java version: jdk17

base class:

```java
if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")) {
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("--headless");
    setDriver(new ChromeDriver(options));
    Dimension newSize = new Dimension(1936, 1048);
    getDriver().manage().window().setSize(newSize);
    System.out.println("Current screen size :" + getDriver().manage().window().getSize());
}
# page class:
WebDriver driver;

public SignUp(WebDriver driver) {
    this.driver = driver;
    PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
}

@FindBy(xpath = "//div[text()='Login']")
private WebElement loginBtn;

public HomePage clickLogin() {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(30));
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(loginBtn));
    loginBtn.click();
    return this;
}
# HTML:
<form class="">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <div class="flex flex-col-reverse ...">
                ...
                <button type="submit" class="button_animation activeState[1px] border-solid border-primaryLight dark:border-primaryDark text-center rounded-lg !w-full active:bg-primaryLight active:scale-[.96]">
                    <span class="z-10">Login</span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```